# Overloading operator + for fractions (using lcm)

Tags: c++

I want to compute the sum of two fraction using lcm of numerator and denominator. That means as a result I want to get  a fraction in the reduced form. I have the following cpp file.

```
#include <iostream> //need it for cin and cout
#include "fraction.h"
Fraction::Fraction()
{
   num = 1;
   den = 1;
}

Fraction::Fraction(int n, int d)
{
   int tmp_gcd = gcd(n, d);

   num = n / tmp_gcd;
   den = d / tmp_gcd;
}

int Fraction::gcd(int a, int b)
{
   int tmp_gcd = 1;

// Implement GCD of two numbers;

   return tmp_gcd;
 }

 int Fraction::lcm(int a, int b)
 {
return a * b / gcd(a, b);

 }
 Fraction operator+(const Fraction&a,const Fraction &b)
 {
    int c=(lcm(b.den,a.den)/b.den)*a.num+b.num*(lcm(b.den,a.den)/a.den);
    int d=lcm(b.den,a.den);
    Fraction result(c,d);
    return result;
 }
```

However this code does not work because lcm is not defined in this scope.

What is the key that allows lcm work in this scope? If you please could explain more, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lcm` is a member of `Fraction`. You can refer to it just as `lcm` within members of `Fraction`; but `operator+` isn't a member, so you'll have to use the qualified name `Fraction::lcm`.

It will also need to be `static`. (Hopefully it already is, but I can't see the declaration to be sure).

Comment: Although `lcm` probably isn't part of the public interface of `class Fraction` at all, and could just be moved into the implementation file as a helper function at namespace scope.  `gcd` too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! another quick question; Is it declared as static because there must be an internal linkage set up?

Comment: @user3501: No, for a member function `static` means it's associated with the class itself, independently of any object. If it weren't static, you'd have to call it on an object, `something.lcm(a,b)`, which wouldn't make any sense. As Ben Voigt said, it might make more sense not to be a member at all; but if it is, then it needs to be static.